# How to change current window programatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

If I have multiple windows open, I want to be able to cycle through them at my leisure, to change which one is on top and active.

How can this be done, if at all?

Comment: Using a Chrome Extension?

Comment: I need to do this with the code of the extension, yes.

Comment: It appears to be possible using `chrome.tabs.update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it about tabs? If it's about windows, then, you may want to take a look at this page.
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows.html

Comment: No, not tabs...separate windows which may or may not have multiple tabs each.

Comment: But indeed it is possible with chrome.windows.update with the focused property. Perfect.